# Opera scripts and storing states(like GM_SetValue in greasemonkey)

Tags: greasemonkey, opera, userscripts

Is there a way to store state of user script in opera? In GreaseMonkey one can use GM_SetValue/GM_GetValue. I saw one script that emulates them in opera using cookies but I don't like this idea for several reasons(mainly for limitied size of cookies). Is there another way to store state?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 idea:

**1. Google Gears**

[Google Gears](http://labs.opera.com/news/2009/02/20/) has [Database API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_database.html). You can store & get data with SQL.
I know it's over spec for your purpose, but I suppose this way is simply one.

**2. SharedObject (Flash)**

Flash can be stored data to local using **[SharedObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object)**.
It's similar to cookie, but larger than cookie.

- cookie: 4kb
- SharedObject: 100kb (default)

Answer (score 1):

**Violentmonkey**, at least, supports GM_(delete/getset)Value.
But I'm sure the internet ones too, no?

Before using those, I used [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage), which is really great.

They are compatible with every browsers today (even opera 12).

It's like cookies as it's per site: a website will only see it's own local storage.
GM_setValue is per userscript.
But in practice, as a userscript is often written for one website, it will be the same.

You have this:

```
localStorage.setItem(name, value)
localStorage.getItem(name)
localStorage.removeItem(name)
```

In terms of capacity, GM_setValue is only limited by your HDD space, localStorage had limited capacity but quite big and then cookies has very limited capacity.